# SQL: Update column (username) with content from another column in same table (email address)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to update the username of everyone in the wordpress users table so their email address becomes their username.

I'm a total SQL muppet, so assume you're explaining this to a slightly stupid 5 year old :)

I was going to try something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET usernamecolumn = emailaddresscolumn
```

But as I have noooo idea what I'm doing, I figured I should ask here first!

Comment: Did I do that? Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt would be correct.

```
UPDATE WordpressUsers
SET username = emailaddress;
```

However there could be some 'gotchas' when you try this.

You'll need to ensure the `emailaddress` can fit within the size of the `username` column.

```
-- Verify length to avoid truncation during UPDATE
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(emailaddress)) FROM WordpressUsers;
```

Then `ALTER` your table to allow for the increased data length.

```
ALTER TABLE WordpressUsers
MODIFY username VARCHAR(200);
```

### Example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WordpressUsers;

CREATE TABLE WordpressUsers (
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    emailaddress VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO WordpressUsers (username, emailaddress)
VALUES ('joesmith', 'joe.smith@test.com')
    , ('janedoe', 'jane.doe@test.com')
    , ('johndoe', 'john.doe@test.com')
    , ('someone', 'someone@test.com')
    , ('someone', 'ReallyLongLongEmailAddress@ReallyReallyLongDomain.com');

-- verify        
SELECT * FROM WordpressUsers;

-- Verify length to avoid truncation during UPDATE
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(emailaddress)) FROM WordpressUsers;

ALTER TABLE WordpressUsers
MODIFY username VARCHAR(200);

-- UPDATE
UPDATE WordpressUsers
SET username = emailaddress;


-- verify        
SELECT * FROM WordpressUsers;
```

[image]

[image]

[[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/SWQ22362)

Comment: Far out, thanks so much @Brien. _Perfect!_ I love stackoverflow.